# How to select all text inside a SelectionContainer in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textselection, jetbrains-compose

Consider a `LazyColumn` inside a `SelectionContainer` that contains some composables  like this:

```kotlin
SelectionContainer {
  LazyColumn {
    repeat(50) { n ->
      item {
        Row {
          Text("Some item:")
          Button(onClick = { println(n) }) { Text("the item is $n") }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The selection works well, but only in visible area of the scrollable `LazyColumn`. Then, how to select the entire considering the hidden part in scrollable area, such like doing a "`Ctlr + A`" (desktop) or "long click" (mobile)?

I saw that the `SelectionContainer` is a wrap to another constructor of the same function, which have another params to set, such as `Selection` state, but that function is internal to the jetpack compose package. Then, there's a way to immplement "custom"/"programmatically" selection with the standard composable or should we create an custom selectable composable to work like we need?

By the end, if this composable is not useful in this case, how a good way to implement that behaviour?